# Can I ask too many questions?

Tags: support, questions

I watch TV very frequently and have a lot of questions. However, I feel like I can't ask all of them at once because it could flood the Active Questions, stealing away from other users. So I want to know something. Can I ask too many questions?

Comment: Stack Exchange does have rate limits on users though i can't remember the link which details them. i quite sure even higher rep users can only post so many questions a day and so many a month

Comment: How many questions are we talking about?

Comment: I'm really not sure about you leaving a bunch of questions for others to ask on your behalf.  What would be the purpose of that?  If your questions are good and of a high quality - and as long as you are literally not flooding the board with questions, just go ahead and start asking them.

Comment: Yes you can ask too many question as long as they are all on topic. But remember to be responsive of all the feedback and quality of questions to get good response. And remember there are few [limits too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/182734) and remeber to ask one question per post.

Answer (score 2):

If you do ask many questions, you should also take the time to read, comment (if needed), upvote, and accept answers from people who take the time to work on answers.

If you start asking such many questions that you don't even have the time to review the answers, people (answerers) will start to think you are not thankful on their work.

So the limit will be set by the time you will have to review answers.

Also take in consideration that writing a good question takes some time, as you will probably have to provide links, quotes, details to help the answerers.